# send data from Blackberry application to another running application(and not running application)?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

1. send data from Blackberry application to another running application??((plz no listening thread))
2. Call Application by parameter from another application??
3. create one cod file for both application(make the first depend on other)??

sry form my bad english

Answer (score 0):

1. See this article at BlackBerry support forums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Launch-a-third-party-application-from-another-third-party/ta-p/444753
2. & 3. There are many ways to do this. The best way would depend on what you want to do. But, since you want both applications to be distributed in a single COD file, I would suggest you use multiple entry points, and have a look here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-do-multiple-entry-points-communicate/td-p/411393